# Сервер на python не хочет подключать больше 1 клиента

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, сокет

Доброе утром всем товарищем программистам. Я написал программу для одногруппников, чтобы вместо денег использовать валюту в Python. Однако, возникла проблема с подключением к серверу, поскольку только один клиент может подключиться, хотя в программе установлено значение "2" для `serversocket.listen(2)`. Знакомый мне посоветовал попробовать библиотеку `threading`, так что я попробую сейчас использовать этот модуль.

**Как работает мой сервер:**
Когда клиент подключается, сервер генерирует уникальный идентификатор для клиента и сохраняет начальное значение счета в словаре. Затем сервер ожидает сообщения от клиента с указанием суммы и идентификатора получателя. После получения сообщения сервер проверяет, существует ли получатель в словаре клиентов. Если да, то сервер обновляет счета отправителя и получателя, и отправляет клиенту информацию о новых счетах. Если получатель не существует, сервер отправляет сообщение об ошибке.

**Код клиента:**

Этот код представляет собой клиентскую часть программы, которая подключается к серверу по сокету, взаимодействуя с ним через TCP-соединение. Клиент получает уникальный идентификатор от сервера при подключении, после чего вы можете отправлять запросы серверу, указывая количество очков и идентификатор получателя. В ответ на запрос, сервер обрабатывает данные, меняя количество очков у отправителя и получателя, затем отправляет ответ обновленный баланс отправителя и получателя.

Когда вы вводите `quit`, клиент отправляет это сообщение серверу и закрывает соединение.

**Цель:** Сделать так, чтобы к серверу смогли одновременно смогли подключиться хотя бы на данный момент всего два клиента. Также, следует внести изменения в программу для оптимизации её производительности и устойчивости, так чтобы серверы не "падал" и не завершал работу слишком часто. **Но приоритетной для меня целью является разобраться с подключением клиентом!** Заранее спасибо человеку, который поможет мне!

**Код сервера:**

```py
import socket
import random

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "localhost" 
port = 12345 
server_socket.bind((host, port))

server_socket.listen(2)

print("Сервер запущен на порту", port)

clients = {}

def handle_client(client_socket, client_address):
    id_value = str(random.randint(100000, 999999))
    clients[id_value] = 100  

    client_socket.send(id_value.encode())

    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        print("Получено от клиента:", data)

        if data == "quit":
            break


        amount, recipient_id = data.split(",")
        amount = int(amount)

   
        if recipient_id in clients:
    
            sender_score = clients[id_value]
            sender_score -= amount
            clients[id_value] = sender_score

            
            recipient_score = clients[recipient_id]
            recipient_score += amount
            clients[recipient_id] = recipient_score

           
            response = "Ваши очки: {}\nСчет получателя: {}".format(sender_score, recipient_score)
            client_socket.send(response.encode())
        else:
            error_msg = "Неверный идентификатор получателя"
            client_socket.send(error_msg.encode())

   
    del clients[id_value]

  
    client_socket.close()

while True:
   
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    print("Установлено соединение с клиентом", client_address)

   
    handle_client(client_socket, client_address)
```

**Код клиента:**

```py
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Подключение к серверу
host = "localhost" 
port = 12345 
client_socket.connect((host, port))

client_id = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()

print("Ваш id:", client_id)

while True:
    amount = input("Введите количество очков для отправки ('quit' для выхода): ")
    if amount == "quit":
        client_socket.send(amount.encode())
        break

    recipient_id = input("Введите id получателя: ")

    data = "{},{}".format(amount, recipient_id)
    client_socket.send(data.encode())

    response = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(response)

client_socket.close()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506460/python-simple-socket-client-server-using-asyncio

Comment: @СергейШ Asyncio **не нужен в этом коде, так как он используется для асинхронных операций**, а этот код является синхронным. В данном случае все операции выполняются последовательно и не требуют параллельного выполнения. Таким образом, использование `asyncio` будет избыточным и не приведет к улучшению производительности.

Comment: @Nymos asyncio  никогда не приводит к улучшению производительности. Оно для другого: чтоб ответить второму клиенту пока ждем первого.

Comment: @eri Ну так моя задача состоит в том, чтобы в сети могли одновременно быть два пользователя

Comment: Избавится от "quit", что избавить вас от бесконечного цикла в фунцуций handle_client. У клиента сначала запрашиваем все данные у пользователя, открываем соединение, отправляем данные, закрываем соединение

Comment: @СергейШ не поможет. Ацепт заблокирован же

Comment: @eri что значить Ацепт?

Comment: да я уже разобрался, как решить свою проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я смог решить свою проблему, используя библиотеку `threading`.  Я его использую для обработки одновременно нескольких клиентов. Когда клиент подключается к моему серверу, создается новый поток **(thread)**, который обрабатывает взаимодействие с этим клиентом, позволяя серверу обрабатывать другие клиенты параллельно.

Однако, **хочу предупредить сразу!**  Если вы захотите использовать мой способ, то нужно учесть, что **хоть и библиотека `threading` позволяет обрабатывать несколько клиентов одновременно, но а так же увеличивает нагрузку на сервер!**

Сейчас я буду пробовать правильно организовывать и управлять потоками. Если вы напишите совет, как это сделать лучше, то буду благодареy.

**Как теперь выглядит сервер:**

```py
import socket
import random
import threading

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "localhost"
port = 12345
server_socket.bind((host, port))

server_socket.listen(2)

print("Сервер запущен на порту", port)

clients = {}
lock = threading.Lock()

def handle_client(client_socket, client_address):
    id_value = str(random.randint(100000, 999999))

    with lock:
        clients[id_value] = 100

    client_socket.send(id_value.encode())

    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        print("Получено от клиента:", data)

        if data == "quit":
            break

        if data == "/balance":
            with lock:
                response = "Ваши очки: {}".format(clients[id_value])
                client_socket.send(response.encode())
        elif data.startswith("/trade"):
            _, recipient_id, amount = data.split()
            amount = int(amount)

            with lock:
                if recipient_id in clients and amount <= clients[id_value]:
                    sender_score = clients[id_value]
                    sender_score -= amount
                    clients[id_value] = sender_score

                    recipient_score = clients[recipient_id]
                    recipient_score += amount
                    clients[recipient_id] = recipient_score

                    response = "Очки успешно отправлены"
                    client_socket.send(response.encode())
                else:
                    response = "Ошибка при отправке очков"
                    client_socket.send(response.encode())
        else:
            response = "Неверная команда"
            client_socket.send(response.encode())

    with lock:
        del clients[id_value]

    client_socket.close()

def start_server():
    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print("Установлено соединение с клиентом", client_address)

        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket, client_address))
        client_thread.start()

start_server()
```

**Как теперь выглядит код клиента:**

```py
import socket

host = "localhost"
port = 12345

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((host, port))

client_id = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print("Подключено к серверу. Ваш идентификатор:", client_id)

while True:
    command = input("Введите команду: ")

    if command.lower() == 'quit':
        client_socket.send('quit'.encode())
        break
    elif command.lower() == '/balance':
        client_socket.send('/balance'.encode())
        response = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        print("Ваши очки:", response)
    elif command.startswith('/trade'):
        _, recipient_id, amount = command.split()
        trade_command = "/trade {} {}".format(recipient_id, amount)
        client_socket.send(trade_command.encode())
        response = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        print(response)
    else:
        print("Неверная команда")

client_socket.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Используйте Фреймворк, а не голый сокет. Например минимальный стандартный

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html

Тред сервер чтоб обрабатывать блокирующие вещи одновременно, пример из доков:

```
import socket
import threading
import socketserver

class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        data = str(self.request.recv(1024), 'ascii')
        cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
        response = bytes("{}: {}".format(cur_thread.name, data), 'ascii')
        self.request.sendall(response)

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

def client(ip, port, message):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.connect((ip, port))
        sock.sendall(bytes(message, 'ascii'))
        response = str(sock.recv(1024), 'ascii')
        print("Received: {}".format(response))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Port 0 means to select an arbitrary unused port
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 0

    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    with server:
        ip, port = server.server_address

        # Start a thread with the server -- that thread will then start one
        # more thread for each request
        server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
        # Exit the server thread when the main thread terminates
        server_thread.daemon = True
        server_thread.start()
        print("Server loop running in thread:", server_thread.name)

        client(ip, port, "Hello World 1")
        client(ip, port, "Hello World 2")
        client(ip, port, "Hello World 3")

        server.shutdown()
```

Comment: Спасибо больше, начну изучать ваш способ

Comment: socketserver.ThreadingMixIn тут ключевая штука, сервер запускать можно без треда.

Comment: Есть ещё asyncio protocol server. Но там надо будет реализовать неблокирующий ридлайн.

Comment: Есть и асинкио стрим сервер, похож на сокетсервер, но может работать без тредов.